# Adding managedObjectContext objects with an NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, osx-yosemite

I have this application that is using core data and an NSArrayController to manage some objects in a table. I have the code below to pick up some objects on a directory. My questions is about the section below labeled "Handle Files". I create a new Video object using the url, I copy the metadata attributes using a custom function I wrote. The object is now inserted in the managedObjectContext. My question is, since I have my NSArrayController bound to my managedObjectContext, why do I have to still do [self addObject:newVideo] to have the object shown on my table? Is there a way to force the array controller to pull the object from the managedObjectContext without having to manually add it? It will be a hassle having to be updating both things every time I add or remove an object.

```
for (NSURL *url in _dirEnumerator) {
    NSNumber *_isDirectory = nil;
    [url getResourceValue:&_isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:NULL];
    if (![_isDirectory boolValue]) {
        if (([_mediaTypes containsObject:[[url pathExtension]uppercaseString]])) {
            // Handle the files
            Video *newVideo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Video" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
            [newVideo copyAttributesFrom:url];
            [self addObject:newVideo];
            NSLog(@"Inserting video: %@",[newVideo valueForKey:@"name"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had my bindings all wrong an the array controller was not feeding my table correctly. You cannot sneak objects behind the array controller, if you implement the array controller you must let him do his job and that includes adding and removing objects. He will take care of letting the tableview know when things have changed.